# how to handle ajax request on success or failer

Tags: jquery

i just have a small problem with jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/XGM67/

when i click on vote i send data to server
server sends response 1 on success 0 on failure

how ever if i refresh the page and and click on vote - 
the **target.html('Voted').addClass('voted');** is applyed again

**i want that to show up only one time if any voted link has been clicked - i mean the class dose not applied to the rest of voted links**

**i just don't know how to handle that - any help please - thank you in advanced**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
 $("#container .bar a").click(function(e) {

   // e.preventDefault();

   var target = $(this);

   $('span a').removeAttr('href');

   $('span a').off('click');

   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   var ip = '<?php echo ipAddress(); ?>';

    $.ajax({

      url: 'listener.php',

      data:'id='+ id +'&ip=' + ip, 

      success: function( response ){

       // here every thing is working       
       $('#msg').show(400);

       $('span a').removeAttr('href');

        $('span a').off('click');

         target.html('Voted').addClass('voted');

      }
    }); 

        return false;      
    });         
});
```

Comment: The key point is "if I refresh the page". Everything is reset, including those classes you added, which means you need to set those classes and do whatever else you need on page load; probably easiest on the PHP side before the page is rendered, that way when the client receives the page, its already properly set up. Based on the code you've posted, I assume you'd simply need to check whether this IP address has already voted on this link, and conditionally apply the class and href attributes as needed.

Comment: thanks Teeg, for help, i am not expert with jquery, how ever, i know my implementation is not perfect, i think it could be hard for me again to rebuild it again correctly, so i though it could be any solution for this small problem. :-)